# Flask app-setting up page dependency for LDAP login

Tags: apache, python-3.x, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I   have  2  webpages /login  and /index . I  could  set  up dependency for entering /index  page  once login  is authenticated  from LDAP  using  the  following view function and it works perfectly with this:
           `@app.route('/index',methods=['GET','POST'])
            def index():
               return render_template('index.html')
           @app.route('/')
           @app.route('/login',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
           def login():
              error=None
              if request.method =='POST':
                  s = Server('appauth.corp.domain.com:636', use_ssl=True, get_info=ALL)
                       c=Connection(s,user=request.form['username'],password=request.form['password'],check_names=True, lazy=False,raise_exceptions=False)
                  c.open()
                  c.bind()
                  if request.form['username'] not in users and (c.bind() != True) is True:
                error='Invalid credentials. Please try again'
                else:
                    return redirect(url_for('index'))
                    return render_template('login.html',error=error)`

Excuse   the indentation for the first line and c=Connection(s,user=request.form['username'],password=request.form['password'],check_names=True, lazy=False,raise_exceptions=False) 
`
I  am  able   to access /index  page by bypassing  the  login page. I found that  there  is  a  way to set up a decorator @login_required  using flask_login. But  that  would  involve setting  up a  local database  using SQLAlchemy . Is there  a easier way of doing that  as I would   need   to  modify my login log otherwise.

In the  login page  i am calling index.html, I  am using this  as  my base.hml

`{% extends 'index.html' %}

Comment: You might be able to get your webserver to do that for you. What webserver are you using? IE Apache, IIS, NGINX, etc. -- Otherwise, your routes will need some way of verifying the user has been authenticated. Flask-Login doesn't necessarily require SQLAlchemy or particular database.

Comment: @sytech  I am using Apache webserver with mod_wsgi

Comment: You can configure Apache to authenticate via LDAP before serving the app content. There are lots of tutorials available to assist you in making this configuration, if it suits your needs.

Comment: @sytech  Thanks Much, I  will  try to figure this out !!

Comment: @sytech   is it possible to call the  c.bind()  which I used in @app.route('/login',methods=['GET', 'POST'])   in the @app.route('/index',methods=['GET','POST']) ,I can check  if it is "True"   then proceed to load the /index page

Comment: @sytech , I mean  would  using Flask sessions  help here?

Comment: You could use a `before-request` decorator to do the check in your code, yes. But you'd probably be better off configuring Apache to do this and benefit from their authentication modules. Sessions are key to the ideal solution. Better if you integrate that with Flask-Login. -- That's what Flask-Login helps you manage. As I mentioned already, you don't necessarily need to use SQLAlchemy with flask-login. It's agnostic of your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Implemented it successfully  using sessions. This   is exactly what is   needed for this

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/quickstart/#sessions